# Continue vibration even after the screen goes to sleep mode in Android

Tags: java, android, android-service

In my application, I am starting the VIBRATOR_SERVICE through the following code

```
long[] pattern = {50,100,1000}
Vibrator vibe=(Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vibe.vibrate(pattern, 0);
```

I want the vibration continue till I call

```
vibe.cancel();
```

The Code is working fine, but the vibration getting off when the screen goes to sleep mode.

I want the vibration continue even after the screen goes to sleep mode. Is there any ways to do this? Please help me.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: As i know you can done this by acquire the wakelock to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer to the question is as follows

Before doing this, don't forget to add the permission "`android.permission.VIBRATE`" to your app manifest file.

```
public BroadcastReceiver vibrateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            vibe.vibrate(pattern, 0);
        }
    }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(vibrateReceiver, filter);
```

**wakelock** will not work here, because the receiver will receive the intent only after the screen goes off. Though we can acquire the wakelock after the screen goes to off mode the vibration stops, because it happens with the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`. So it can be done by starting the vibration again after receiving the broadcast.

Comment: Thanks to TGMCians for giving me the idea of broadcast receiver. I have explained why his answer is not apt for my requirement in my answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this (i.e. vibrate in sleep mode) in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might help you. First make `broadcast receiver` for this such that when mobile light screen off then write logic of vibrate mobile.

```
 public BroadcastReceiver wakeLockReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            //WRITE LOGIC OF VIBRATION.
        }
    }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(wakeLockReceiver, filter);
```

Add permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain the code? Do u think this code make my device vibrate even after the screen goes to sleep mode?

Comment: As i think it will vibrate the mobile. try to do like this.

Comment: I tried your code. But unfortunately I am getting error when executing the statement "wakeLock.acquire(15*1000);". and the Error is "java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x40000000 }".

Comment: @Anu I think now there is no need to to add permission "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK". Try without write this.